# Jquery Accordion to dl>dd+dt after Backbone Rendered code?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, html-lists

I created a DL, DT, DD definition list, with Backbone with Coffeescript.
I used template in my html page below.
There is no problem, succesfully rendering html.
I looked html in chrome and elements are OK.

After all this i tried to make an accordion.
And wanted to try all DT hide.
But couldnt make any Jquery code to this tags.

i used console;

```
 $(function () {    
       var allDD= $('div#userList dl').html();
       console.log(allDD);
      });
```

But nothing log !

i searched web nothing found.
Also tried;

```
 $(document).ready and window.onload()
```

But still nothing happened.

How can i make an accordion effect to codes after Backbone render.

Please any help?

```
  <div id="userList"> 
      // DL > DT+DD will be here
  </div>

  <script type="text/template" id="tpl-user-results">
  <dl class="users"></dl>
  </script>

  <script type="text/template" id="tpl-user-row-dt">
      <span class="percent"><%= Math.ceil(dt.score) %></span>
      <a href="#" class=""> <%= dt.username %> (<%= dt.score%>) </a>
  </script> 

  <script type="text/template" id="tpl-user-row-dd">
      <span class="percent"> <%= dd.username %> (<%= dd.score%>) 
      <img src="/user/0001.jpg">
      <p>User Info : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus reiciendis corporis hic consequatur alias veniam repudiandae architecto. Maiores aliquid sint cupiditate voluptate modi debitis ipsum consequuntur quaerat odit id ipsa.</p>
  </script>
```

Comment: Could you provide the Backbone code too?

Comment: There is no problem in Backbone code, everyhting in DOM what i want. In chrome console i can take dd or dt. But my problem is in my html page jquery console doesnt make anything...

Comment: If the DOM isn't being correctly populated by your view then clearly there is a problem in your Backbone code.

Comment: DOM correctly populating DL>DT+DD. It is ok for me. But after all this i want to make accordion and JQuery doesnt make anyhting?

Comment: Sorry Friend, code is too long so i couldnt paste it. My problem was not in Backbone, i asked only with a rendered Backbone html dom. can i make jquery functions to DOM, below the html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
var allDD= $('div#userList dl').html();
```

Should be in your `render` method on your view, after you've actually rendered the HTML code.

Example:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(someTemplate);
    this.$el.accordion();
    this.$("dt").hide();
}
```

Comment: DOM correctly populating DL>DT+DD. It is ok for me. But after all this i want to make accordion and JQuery doesnt make anyhting? Should i make it in Backbone render() ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.